# How do you pick a certain min number in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running a program which corrects responses to tests. There are 23 questions and each correct answer is given a + 1. My code sums these scores up for these 23 questions and creates a separate column (totalCorrect) which prints the final score out of 23. I have attached a screenshot of a portion of this column [totalCorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgYne.png)

What I want to do right now, is to assign a money incentive based on each performance. The incentive is 0.3$ for every right answer - the issue is, every survey has 23 questions but I only want to consider 20 of these questions to calculate the incentive. So out of the score (out of 23) we will consider only a min of 20 responses.

How can I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
df['numCorrect'] = min{20, totalNumCorrect}
df['earnedAmount'] = 0.3 * df['numCorrect']
```

where 'earnedAmount' is trying to calculate the final incentive amount and numberCorrect is trying to isolate only 20 points out of a possible 23

Comment: `min(20, totalNumCorrect)`. Your braces are incorrect, and should be parenthesis.

Comment: But if `totalNumCorrect` is a Pandas series or NumPy array, the above will not work. This works only for a single value of `totalNumCorrect`.

Comment: Given the use of `df`, I assume you're using dataframes and Pandas. If so, please tag your question with the `pandas` tag.